# Should I quit if I'm not being assigned to any job?

Tags: professionalism

Should I quit my job if I always got lots of free time and I'm only assigned to do petty things and not the important ones. I believe one of the reasons is my clumsiness. I always make stupid mistakes even I try to be careful. Besides what should I do if I want to be a competent worker and improve myself so that  I don't be such a klutz at my work.

Comment: Quitting is fully up to you, if you no longer find your work a good fit for you you should search for one that does. Regarding your second question we need more details on you job and how/where you perform not so good, so we can suggest alternatives you can take.

Comment: That being said, I'm afraid both questions seem off topic here on The Workplace, please read the topics exposed on the Help section so you get a better understanding of how and what to ask here. Then I suggest you edit your question accordingly, so it is not closed.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your boss.  If you've been under-performing, then your boss will have some kind of idea about what criteria you need to meet in order to get back to proper tasks again.  You might need more training or supervision to get you back up to speed.

This may mean a certain period of you performing non-important tasks to demonstrate some reliability.

It's also possible that you've been given menial tasks as encouragement for you to leave of your own accord.

If you're not comfortable with the idea of doing the tasks that you've been failing with, then it makes sense for you to look for another job that you **can** do and not resign until you've found that new job.

Comment: Talk to your boss,  it may be that they have work planned for you that just hasn't materialized yet.   It is also possible to create your own job in most environments:  look for things that are affecting everyone elses productivity and fix them if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Should you quit?

Not unless you're prepared to be unemployed.

Comment: Well,you say you "believe"; be sure, before thinking about leaving. Talk with your manager, ask him directly, and be ready to propose improvement ideas (could be a course or anything really).